# C# largest prime factor with modulo?

Tags: c#, for-loop, if-statement, prime-factoring

I was wondering if it is possible to find the largest prime factor of a number by using modulos in C#.  In other words, if `i % x == 0` then we could break a `for` loop or something like that, where `x` is equal to all natural numbers below our `i` value.

How would I specify the `all natural numbers below our i value` as equal to our x variable?  It becomes a little tedious to write out conditionals for every single integer if you know what I'm saying.

By the way, I'm sure there is a *far* easier way to do this in C#, so please let me know about it if you have an idea, but I'd also like to try and solve it this way, just to see if I can do it with my beginner knowledge.

Here is my current code if you want to see what I have so far:

```
static void Main()
{
    int largestPrimeFactor = 0;

    for (long i = 98739853; i <= 98739853; i--)
    {
        if (true)
        {
            largestPrimeFactor += (int) i;
            break;
        }
    }

    Console.WriteLine(largestPrimeFactor);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: This code will do nothing. It will break during first iteration. Also the condition in `for` is wrong.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number Sieve is probably the easiest way to do this. Doing a loop of some sort would take way too long. You basically create a list and start getting rid of all the multiples of the next smallest integer up to the sqrt(the value). So, you start @ 2 and get rid of everything that is divisible by 2, then go to the next number which is 3. Get rid of all numbers that are divisible by 3, then 5 since 4 was deleted from 2, etc...

Answer (score 5):

If I were to do this using loop and modulos I would do:

```
long number = 98739853;
long biggestdiv = number;

while(number%2==0) //get rid of even numbers
    number/=2;

long divisor = 3;

if(number!=1)
while(divisor!=number)
{
    while(number%divisor==0)
    {
        number/=divisor;
        biggestdiv = divisor;
    }

    divisor+=2;
}
```

In the end, `biggestdiv`  would be the largest prime factor.

Note: This code is written directly in browser. I didn't try to compile or run it. This is only for showing my concept. There might be algorithm mistakes. It they are, let me know. I'm aware of the fact that it is not optimized at all (I think Sieve is the best for this).

**EDIT:**
fixed: previous code would return 1 when `number` were prime.
fixed: previous code would end in loop leading to overflow of `divisor` where `number` were power of 2

Answer (score 3):

Ooh, this sounds like a fun use for iterator blocks. Don't turn this in to your professor, though:

```
private static List<int> primes = new List<int>() {2};
public static IEnumerable<int> Primes()
{
    int p;
    foreach(int i in primes) {p = i; yield return p;}

    while (p < int.MaxValue)
    {
       p++;

       if (!primes.Any(i => p % i ==0))
       {
           primes.Add(p);
           yield return p;
       }
    }          
}

public int LargestPrimeFactor(int n)
{
     return Primes.TakeWhile(p => p <= Math.Sqrt(n)).Where(p => n % p == 0).Last();
}
```

Comment: It will cause to stack over flow if your n is bigger than 2*10^9

Comment: Thanks for this, I'm just doing this for fun though, no professor! :)

Comment: Well, yeah, ~2 billion is about int.MaxValue.

Comment: Good point, for example the most common of this question I see is Project Euler which is 600b and 2*10^9 is 200b. Very elegant procedure though. Shows a decent understanding of the language.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure quite what your question is: perhaps you need a loop over the numbers?  However there are two clear problems with your code:

- Your for loop has the same stop and end value. Ie it will run once and once only
- You have a break before the largestPrimeFactor sum. This sum will NEVER execute, because break will stop the for loop ( and hence execution of that block). The compiler should be giving a warning that this sum is unreachable.

Comment: I see you've fixed the break order. Still it is in an if true statement so that will break from executing the loop (which is of only one iteration anyway)

Comment: Well, I'm trying to find out how I could find the largest prime factor of a number by using modulos.  If it is even possible, and if so, how to do it.  And the true is just a placeholder, once I can find out if it is possible to use a conditional utilizing modulos some how.

Comment: First get a simple prime number tester working. You might want to then add a cache mechanism - eg. An array of Results (untested, prime, not-prime). Then add a loop that starts at half N and count down to 2. The loop stops when a prime factor is found.